# Error create multi navigation on Zend 2

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2

I using module Application

on module.config.php

```
...
    // Navigation
    'navigation' => array(
        'default' => array(
            array(
                'label' => 'Product Management',
                'route' => 'product',
            ),
        ),
        'outlet' => array(
            array(
                'label' => 'Outlet Management',
                'route' => 'outlet',
            ),
            array(
                'label' => 'Delivery Order',
                'route' => 'deliveryorder',
            ),
        ),
    ),
...
```

and layout.phtml

```
<?php 
echo $this->navigation('navigation')->menu()->setUlClass('nav navbar-nav');
echo $this->navigation('outlet_navigation')->menu()->setUlClass('nav navbar-nav'); 
?>
```

Error appear when call outlet navigation. How to fix it ?

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a service for each navigation entry.

Assuming you have this:

```
'service_manager' => array(
 'factories' => array(
     'navigation' => 'Zend\Navigation\Service\DefaultNavigationFactory',
 ),
),
```

You will only get the default navigation entries.

If you switch to the Abstract Factory:

```
'service_manager' => array(
    'abstract_factories' => array(
        'Zend\Navigation\Service\NavigationAbstractServiceFactory'
    ),
),
```

You can then do:

```
echo $this->navigation('Zend\Navigation\Default')->menu();
echo $this->navigation('Zend\Navigation\Outlet')->menu();
```